# getting error for javax servelet in eclipse

Tags: java

I have imported the following:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;
```

in above two statement i am getting error as The

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException cannot be resolved
```

Please let me know if u need details i will revert immediately. I have tried in build patch but still it is not working

Comment: Are you trying to add the `custom ` tag?

Comment: You need servlet.jar in your classpath. Which you would automatically get from the app server runtime libraries. Did you create your project as Dynamic web project? And do you have any app server setup in your workspace ?